# Datatable.acceptchanges() commits data to the table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, database, datatable

Datatable.acceptchanges commits data to the table...means

will it insert data to the table ..or datatable?

Comment: DataTable. Not the table in db.

Answer (score 14):

The purpose of AcceptChanges() is to let the DataTable know that its data has been saved to the database. All DataRows in the DataTable have their row.RowState set to DataRowState.Unchanged.

It does not save the data to the database. That is done separately.

Comment: This is still somewhat confusing... If I add a row, and it is marked as ADDED, seems by calling DT.ACCEPTCHANGES, the state of the row becomes UNCHANGED... I suppose the confusion comes into play, if after doing so, and I a do DATAADAPTER.UPDATE(DT), does the call look at the now UNCHANGED state and not bother trying to make a change to the database?  Or instead does the UPDATE compare the rows in the DATATABLE against those in the database, regardless of the DT rowstate?

Comment: OKay, if I read this correctly, looks like code calling DT.ACCEPTCHANGES before DA.UPDATE(DT), prevents the dataadapter from doing it's thing.

That is, if you ADD/DELETE/UPDATE a row in datatable, perform an ACCEPTCHANGES, then do a DA.UPDATE(DT), the UPDATE method won't process the row because to it, the "row" is unchanged.

So it seems really, to call it essentially prevents the change from reaching the DB?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The DataAdapter normally manages the DataRow.RowState property. It uses the DataRow.RowState to determine what action to take for that row. If the RowState of given row is DataRowState.Unchanged, it takes no action for that row.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx):

> When AcceptChanges is called, any
>   DataRow object still in edit mode
>   successfully ends its edits. The
>   DataRowState also changes: all Added
>   and Modified rows become Unchanged,
>   and Deleted rows are removed.
>
> The AcceptChanges method is generally
>   called on a DataTable after you
>   attempt to update the DataSet using
>   the DbDataAdapter.Update method.

So your actual database is unaffected.

Comment: But I  thought AcceptChanges is  called  automatically when  we  call the Update method on DataAdaptopr? Do we  need to call AcceptChanges  EXPLICIT LY?

Answer (score 3):

Some people choose to manipulate the data in a datatable, examples are deleting certain rows or hanging all names to uppercase. removing `NULL`'s and so on.

`AcceptChanges` just saves these changes to the datatable.

If you want to commit the changes you need to use a dataadaptor or  use another method to get the data from the datarows in the datatable and commit the changes.

Comment: I see it differently. You stated: '`AcceptChanges` just saves these changes to the datatable.' But the changes are in actuality already saved to the DataTable. AcceptChanges really 'marks' the current changes as not really being changes anymore. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Will only affect the datatable. Not any DB table.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by auto-number field in database, I suggest below
call update methof of data adapter
call update 
/// for auto number  column 
call acceptchanges of datatable

Then re-fill table through oledbadapter. If u do not need to autonumber field, do not add that as a parameter in deletecommand of oledbadapter

Answer (score 0):

Okay - If I have this right, explicitly calling a DT.CommitChanges() will set all rows to UNCHANGED.  And if that is true, when calling DA.UPDATE(DT), any changes you made to the datatable will be ignored.

So it seems, you should only call DT.CommitChanges() for those changes that you DO NOT want to reach the database.

Therefore, changes DO make it to the .NET datatable, regardless of the CommitChanges call, but to get changes to the database table, don't call a CommitChanges prior to performing the DA.Update.  And of course implying that DA.Update must be called to actually pushed the changes to the database...